# Is it a good idea to split data into two json files, one for categorical structure and one for the (raw) data items?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm basically building a quick and dirty course catalog that has multiple hierarchical categories and courses that belong to these categories at different levels.

In the old implementation, each major category is its own HTML page and all the courses related to that category are just written into that page in html. The catalog used to be mainly static so this worked fine but courses and categories might be added a little more frequently now and some of the user view options might change/expand in the future.

I thought I would separate all the raw data (courses and catalog structure) into JSON, then generate the views based on this data. I think this would make it easier to maintain the content without having to deal with a proper CMS or database. Any time I need to add a course I'd just throw it into the json file.

First question: Would you recommend this?

Second question: If you think using JSON for this is a good idea, would you separate the categorical structure from the courses as two JSON files and then manipulate them with JS? Or would you have one JSON with the course data embedded inside the catalog category structure?

Here is a sample of what I was thinking about. Maybe I would use Underscore to properly merge these two data (course pushed into a "courses" array in the appropriate category) before outputting them into an HTML list view.

```
// JSON of categorical STRUCTURE / HIERARCHY
{
    "catalog":{
        "name":"Course Catalog",
        "categories":[
            {
                "name":"Category A",
                "categories":[
                    {
                        "name":"Category A1",
                        "categories":[
                            {"name":"Category A1a"}
                        ]
                    },{
                        "name":"Category A2",
                        "categories":[
                            {"name":"Category A2a"},
                            {"name":"Category A2b"},
                            {"name":"Category A2c"}
                        ]
                    },{
                        "name":"Category A3",
                        "categories":[
                            {"name":"Category A3a"},
                            {"name":"Category A3b"},
                            {"name":"Category A3c"}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },{
                "name":"Category B"
            },{
                "name":"Category C"
            }
        ]
    }
}

// JSON array of all courses (to be plugged into the structure later through code,
// then output to HTML as nested lists etc.)
{
    "courses":[
        {
            "name":"Course AAA",
            "category":"Category A1a",
            "abstract":"Some sort of short string description.",
            "description":"Some sort of longer string description that will be used in the object."
        },
        {
            "name":"Course BBB",
            "category":"Category A1b",
            "abstract":"Some sort of short string description.",
            "description":"Some sort of longer string description that will be used in the object."
        },
        {
            "name":"Course CCC",
            "category":"Category B",
            "abstract":"Some sort of short string description.",
            "description":"Some sort of longer string description that will be used in the object."
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: How many courses will you have? Will they be updated often? If you have a lot of courses or expect the data to change frequently or in volumes that you don't want to manage by hand, then look into a database.

Comment: Thanks. Estimate around a hundred for now, 300 max before we switch to a better solution. Updates, probably not too often. I'd say once a month. If it were completely up to me I'd probably do exactly what you advise - have a DB and manage it with some CMS. But right now we're looking for a stop gap solution while we transition systems. I'm not sure what future system resources we'll have at our disposal. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First if your data is going to range into the hundreds or thousands of entries I would use a database to manage it. It will just make life a lot simpler and cut down on the chance of data corruption.

It will also speed up your application as database query is much faster then file queries (unless you pre-load your files; but then if you have huge files, pre-loading will also negativity impact your application performance.)

If however you don't have *that many (this is subjective but I would say less then 100)* entries you need to keep track of you could do it the way you propose to with json. (This is almost what [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) does).

If you end up going this way I would do it with the multiple file approach, which would essentially give you the same structure as a multi-table database.

Finally I would look into using [pure](http://beebole.com/pure/) to integrate the json data into your view. Specifically for the 2 file set up look at their examples using [directives and data](http://beebole.com/pure/demos/) (4th example on that page.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think we have about 100 courses that we'll be dealing with. I can't imagine it being more than 300 before we transition to a DB and CMS. We're just not sure what future resources will be available for that kind of project at this point but we need a stop gap solution now.

I'll take a look at pure and the example you cite. Thanks for the pointers!